# Maximizing $\int_0^\infty (1+xy')^2e^y dx$ subject to $\int_0^\infty e^ydx = 1$

Tags: calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, constraints, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I'm trying to solve a calculus of variations-type problem, which requires finding the extrema of:
$$\int_0^\infty (1+xy')^2e^y dx, $$
subject to the constraint that $\int_0^\infty e^ydx = 1$. Intuitively, $e^y$ is the probability density function of some random variable defined on the positive real line, and ideally we should have $y(\infty)\to-\infty$ and $y(0)=C\in[-\infty,\infty]$ as boundary values. Let us define $f=(1+\lambda +2xy'+x^2y'^2)e^y$, I attempt to solve the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0.$$
After some algebra, I arrive at the ODE:
$$ e^y(1-\lambda+4xy'+x^2y'^2+2x^2y'')=0$$
The solution of the ODE is (from Mathematica):
$$ y=c_2-(1+\sqrt{\lambda})\log(x)+2\log(x^\sqrt{\lambda}+c_1). $$
However, this function simply cannot satisfy the constraint $\int_0^\infty e^ydx = 1$, since this integral is divergent for the solution, even when we allow $\sqrt{\lambda}<0$. I am puzzled by this finding. Does this mean that the problem does not have any extrema? Or is this an ill-posed calculus of variations problem and my solution above is completely meaningless?

---

Some further thoughts:
The maximization problem can be further simplified as follows. Expand the square in the target function and use the constraint:
$$\int_0^\infty(1+2xy'+x^2y'^2)e^ydx=1+\int_0^\infty(2xy'+x^2y'^2)e^ydx$$
Now consider the first term in the parenthesis, substituting $f=e^y$ gives:
$$\int_0^\infty2xy'e^ydx=\int_0^\infty 2xf'dx=[2xf]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty 2fdx=-2,$$
For the time being let us just assume that $\lim_{x\to0} xf \to 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} xf \to 0$  as well, so that the above calculation is valid. So the target function can be reduced to the (somewhat) simpler:
$$\int_0^\infty (xy')^2e^y dx.$$
Solving this obviously gives the same Euler-Lagrange equation. I am now convinced that this problem is unbounded. But then what does the solution of the Euler-Lagrange equation tell us?

Comment: The other option to double-check is $\lambda=-k^2,\,k>0$, so $e^y\propto(e^{ik\ln x}+2c_1+c_1^2e^{-ik\ln x})/x$. This is real if $c_1=\pm1$, viz. $e^y\propto(\cos(k\ln x)\pm1)/x$. But that's not integrable either.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative $x\frac{d}{dx}$ suggests that we should change coordinates
$$t~=~\ln x, \qquad q~=~y+t.\tag{A}$$
Then OP's Lagrangian becomes
$$ \tilde{L}~=~(\dot{q}^2 +\lambda)e^q, \qquad t~\in~\mathbb{R}. \tag{B}$$
The [EL equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) becomes
$$ (2\ddot{q}+\dot{q}^2-\lambda)e^q~=~0,\tag{C}$$
with solution
$$ e^{q(t)}~=~\left\{ \begin{array}{lcr}
A\cosh^2\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}(t-t_0)}{2}&{\rm for}& \lambda~>~ 0,\cr
A\cos^2\frac{\sqrt{-\lambda}(t-t_0)}{2}&{\rm for}& \lambda~<~ 0,\cr
A(t-t_0)^2&{\rm for}& \lambda~=~ 0.\end{array}\right.\tag{D}$$
To keep the constraint integral finite, we must choose a trivial solution $$A~=~0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad q(t)~=~-\infty,\tag{E}$$
but even then the constraint is not satisfied.

Comment: Very odd... Would it help to add more constraints to the problem, say, $\int_0^\infty xe^ydx=1$ so that the random variable has a mean of 1?